# Как именно нормализуется NDC?

Tags: opengl

Везде написано что, чтобы получить Нормализованные Координаты Устройства надо разделить x,y,z на w клипа(перспективное деление), но как оно нормализуется? Чему тогда должен быть равен w клипа, чтобы они x,y,z были в диапазоне -1,1? Или же нормализуются x,y,z и потом происходит перспективное деление?

Answer (score 1):

По идее, у вас есть некоторый суп из геометрии, который перемножается на матрицы:

1. Модели, чтобы расположить в мире
2. Вида, чтобы расположить в пространстве которое видит камера
3. Проекции, чтобы преобразовать в видимый куб (или в трапецию, если это перспективная проекция) и отсечь то что камера не видит (за пределами полученного NDC)
4. ну а потом вывести на 2D экран

Другими словами, **для получения NDC делается не "нормализация", а трансформации, после которых идет отсечение** всего что не попадает в кадр (находится за пределами -1..1).

Вот иллюстрация с [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]